# Can I run the same function multiple times with the return value as the argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code is supposed to return a final color value if you give it a string of colours, like

> Colour here:        GG, BG, RG, BR
> Becomes colour:      G, R, B, G

For example: 'RGBG' would return 'B'
Here, i wrote a function to assign color tags (Assign) and another funtion which would feed the broken down primary string. It all works fine when i manually type the  *new_value = assign(main(again))* multiple times depending on the size of the primary string(RGBG -> BRR -> GR ->B; 4 times here but i run the first iteration in advance because the again parameter would have a value to begin with), but returns an empty value when i use *again = assign(main(again))* even though i have given the parameter a value on the previous lines so it's not a "undefined param" error.. i think.

I'm pretty new to this and would greatly appreciate it if you could point me in the right way. Hoping this message finds you in safety :)

```
def assign(xlist):
    for x in range(len(xlist)):
        if xlist[x] in ('BG', 'GB', 'RR'): xlist[x] = 'R'
        elif xlist[x] in ('RG', 'GR', 'BB'): xlist[x] = 'B'
        elif xlist[x] in ('BR'. 'RB', 'GG'): xlist[x] = 'G'
    return ''.join(xlist)

def main(xrow):
    nrow = []
    for i in range(len(xrow)-1):
        nrow.append(xrow[i] + xrow[i+1])
    return(nrow)
        
def triangle(row):
    global again
    again = assign(main(row))
    print(row)
    print(again)
    for k in range(len(row)-1):
        again = assign(main(again))
    return again
```

Comment: `elif xlist[x] in ('RG', 'GR','BB'):` would be quite shorter and maybe better to understand as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
s =  'RGBG'

dict_map = {
    'BG':'R',
    'GB':'R',
    'RR':'R',
    'RG':'B',
    'GR':'B',
    'BB':'B',
    'BR':'G',
    'RB':'G',
    'GG':'G'
    }

def process(s):
    while len(s)!=1:
        s = "".join([dict_map["".join(x)] for x in zip(s[:-1], s[1:])])
    return s

print(process(s))
# B
```

---

Lets break it down:

you can use a dictionary to translate values to other values based on their keys:

`dict_map["BG"]` will return "R". To use the dict we need a list of elements with 2 characters.

We create that list by using the following: `[x for x in zip(s[:-1], s[1:])]` This will return a list of overlapping tupels. E.g. ("R", "G")

Since we cant use this tupels with the dictionary we `"".join()` them together resulting e.g. in "RG".

Now we ask the dictionary which values is used for that key by using `dict_map["RG"]` and get "R" in this case.

The whole thing is done here: `[dict_map["".join(x)] for x in zip(s[:-1], s[1:])]`

Now we have again a list of translated values. We `"".join()` it together again to get a new string: "BRR". We repeat the whole process until the string has a length of 1.